# usd import has no textures / materials

Tags: import

I've tried importing a few of https://developer.nvidia.com/usd#sample in particular the `Kitchen Set` and while the geometry works, the materials don't render in the viewport, nor for a final render in cycles / eevee. Should I expect this to be working yet (blender 3.2.1 master)? I found https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/blender-import-usd-not-importing-materials/194041 but I'm not sure of the state of omniverse blender, and if the changes have been put into the main version of blender at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of `3.2.1` the answer is to use Nvidia's omniverse fork version 3.2.0a, installed through the Omniverse [launcher](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/omniverse/).

Comment: I am still having problems with certain assets for their librarys.

Comment: This was my experience as well, for more complex assets